# Search for specific string in a nested object in mongodb documents using and condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, koa.js

I am trying to search for documents in mongodb that include a specific search string input by the user. Collection that i am trying to search in is named imported_products and my mongodb document structure looks like following.

```
 {
┃     _id: 61add3b16c9e0008e6ad325b,
┃     shop: 'someshop',
┃     shopUserData: { name: 'LoTesting', email: 'vixen@yahoo.com' },
┃     productData: {
┃       title: 'Eyglo 3-in-1 Head Strap for Oculus Quest 2 with Face Silicone Cover & Controllers Grips Covers',
┃       price: 45.99,
┃       priceWithCurrency: '$45.99',
┃       images: [Array],
┃       ASIN: 'B08TWJJ3ZW',
┃       marketPlace: 'www.amazon.com',
┃       settings: [Object],
┃       shopifyProductId: 87187377131097
┃     },
┃     created_at: 2021-12-06T09:11:13.327Z
┃   },
┃   {
┃     _id: 61ae236cac749b088d427497,
┃     shop: 'shomeshop',
┃     shopUserData: { name: 'LoTesting', email: 'test@gmail.com' },
┃     productData: {
┃       title: 'Xbox Series X',
┃       description: 'Amazon Prime customers will have priority access to the Xbox Series X until November 24, 2021.',
┃       price: 'price not available',
┃       priceWithCurrency: 'price not available',
┃       images: [Array],
┃       ASIN: 'B08H75RTZ8',
┃       marketPlace: 'www.amazon.com',
┃       settings: [Object],
┃       shopifyProductId: 5736818278172
┃     },
┃     created_at: 2021-12-06T14:51:24.755Z
┃   },
```

What i need is that, for a specific shop, i need to look up into all of the documents of that shop and inside title property of productData field, i need to search for the query string input by user. So, i need to use $and condition to lookup for the shop and matching query string inside the title property and then i need to return all of the documents matching the condition.

I tried following but i keep getting empty array.

```
const regex = RegExp("/.*" + searchQuery + ".*/");
response = await db
  .collection("imported_products")
  .find({
    $and: [
      { shop: shop },
      { "productData.title": { $regex: regex, $options: "i" } },
    ],
  })
  .toArray();
```

Please guide me to the right path. I am using koa.js for server and next.js for client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually put `$and` as by default all conditions are matched. Also you misspelled `someshop` as `shomeshop` in  document 2, that might be one of the reasons of getting an empty array. You also don't need to use `.*` in `RegExp("/.*" + searchQuery + ".*/")` as by default if the text matches any part of the input, the regex will return true and captures the first match. Passing a regex with the operator `$regex` is also unnecessary. My advice is using `searchQuery.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` instead. The example below should work.

```js
db.collection("imported_products").find({
  shop: shop,
  "productData.title": {
    $regex: searchQuery,
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

You can test the query [here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z_4JCvbDgnO)